# How to implement `thunk` in `redux` with correct way to handle async function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

Here is my store, implemented `thunk`:

`store/index.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reducer from "../reducers/";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export default store;
```

here is my action:

`actions/index`:

```
export const remove = function(id) {
  return {
    type: "remove",
    payload: setTimeout(function() {
      return id;
    }, 2000)
  };
};

export const add = function() {};

export default { remove, add };
```

here is my dispatch function:

`component/Item.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { remove } from "../actions/";

const Item = props => {
  function removeTrigger() {
    props.remove(props.item.id);
  }
  return (
    <li>
      {props.item.name} <button onClick={removeTrigger}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  );
};

function mapAction(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ remove }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapAction
)(Item);
```

on click on `delete` button I am getting a console message. But the id is not removed. any one help me to implement the `thunk` advantage properly here?

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mj1yw80v8j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunk is a middleware that acts whenever you pass a function to an action creator instead of an object. So to dispatch async code, assuming that your component is correctly connected and mapping `dispatchToProps` your async action creator should look something like this:

```
     export const remove = function(id){
         return function(dispatch){
             let id = null
             setTimeout(()=> {
                id = 1
                dispatch({type: 'remove', payload:id})
             }, 3000)
         }
    }
```

You can also receive an extra argument beside `dispatch`, a `getState` function that allows you to access the global state.

Comment: Can you please update my demo as sample, not able to understand properly

Comment: Your `remove` function it's what we call an `actionCreator`, that is exactly that: A function that returns an action(object with a `type` property) to the reducer. All the code passed to a  reducer by definition MUST be  synchronous. In your case you are returning async code to you reducer  in `payload`. This is hapenning because `thunk` will only act when your action creator return a `function` instead of an object, and inside this function, after the async code have finished then you `dispatch` the object